# HTML Table rotated headers on TR/TD independent height

Tags: html, css

I've created this table with a mix of horizontal and vertical headers but I'm not able to control the height of the col-span rows/cols in the middle independently so it's created a lot of un-necessary white-space. How can I control the height of the two sets of rows/cols independently as shown on the picture below.
[image]

```css
th.rotate {
    writing-mode: vertical-lr;
    transform:rotate(-180deg)
    }
```

```html
<table class="table" border="1">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th class="rotate" rowspan="2">
            First Rotated Header</th>
         <th class="rotate" rowspan="2">
            Second Rotated Header</th>
         <th class="rotate" rowspan="2">
            Third Rotated Header</th>
         <th class="rotate" rowspan="2">
            Fourth Rotated Header</th>
         <th class="rotate" rowspan="2">
            Fifth Rotated Header</th>
         <th class="rotate" colspan="1">
            Sisth Rotated Header</th>
         <th class="rotate" colspan="1">
            Seventh Rotated Header</th>
         <th class="rotate" colspan="1">
            Eigth Rotated Header</th>
         <th class="rotate" colspan="1">
            Ninth Rotated Header</th>
         <th colspan="6">
            Large Colspan Group Header</th>
         <th class="thlarge" rowspan="2">
            Additional Comments
         </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th colspan="1">
            1</th>
         <th colspan="1">
            2</th>
         <th colspan="1">
            3</th>
         <th colspan="1">
            4</th>
         <th class="rotate" colspan="1">
            Topic 1 Rotated</th>
         <th class="rotate" colspan="1">Topic 2 Rotated</th>
         <th class="rotate" colspan="1">Topic 3 Rotated</th>
         <th class="rotate" colspan="1">Topic 4 Rotated</th>
         <th class="rotate" colspan="1">Topic 5 Rotated</th>
         <th class="rotate" colspan="1">Topic 6 Rotated</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>01</td>
         <td>02</td>
         <td>03</td>
         <td>04</td>
         <td>05</td>
         <td>06</td>
         <td>07</td>
         <td>08</td>
         <td>09</td>
         <td>10</td>
         <td>11</td>
         <td>12</td>
         <td>13</td>
         <td>14</td>
         <td>15</td>
         <td>Lorem ispum Lorem ispum Lorem ispum Lorem ispum Lorem ispum Lorem ispum Lorem ispum Lorem ispum Lorem ispum</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>01</td>
         <td>02</td>
         <td>03</td>
         <td>04</td>
         <td>05</td>
         <td>06</td>
         <td>07</td>
         <td>08</td>
         <td>09</td>
         <td>10</td>
         <td>11</td>
         <td>12</td>
         <td>13</td>
         <td>14</td>
         <td>15</td>
         <td>Lorem ispum Lorem ispum Lorem ispum Lorem ispum Lorem ispum Lorem ispum Lorem ispum Lorem ispum Lorem ispum</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>01</td>
         <td>02</td>
         <td>03</td>
         <td>04</td>
         <td>05</td>
         <td>06</td>
         <td>07</td>
         <td>08</td>
         <td>09</td>
         <td>10</td>
         <td>11</td>
         <td>12</td>
         <td>13</td>
         <td>14</td>
         <td>15</td>
         <td>Lorem ispum Lorem ispum Lorem ispum Lorem ispum Lorem ispum Lorem ispum Lorem ispum Lorem ispum Lorem ispum</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use three rows as header and adjust the rowspan attributes like this:

```html
<table class="table" border="1">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th class="rotate" rowspan="3">
            First Rotated Header</th>
         <th class="rotate" rowspan="3">
            Second Rotated Header</th>
         <th class="rotate" rowspan="3">
            Third Rotated Header</th>
         <th class="rotate" rowspan="3">
            Fourth Rotated Header</th>
         <th class="rotate" rowspan="3">
            Fifth Rotated Header</th>
         <th class="rotate" rowspan="2">
            Sixth Rotated Header</th>
         <th class="rotate" rowspan="2">
            Seventh Rotated Header</th>
         <th class="rotate" rowspan="2">
            Eigth Rotated Header</th>
         <th class="rotate" rowspan="2">
            Ninth Rotated Header</th>
         <th colspan="6">
            Large Colspan Group Header</th>
         <th class="thlarge" rowspan="3">
            Additional Comments
         </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th class="rotate" rowspan="2">
            Topic 1 Rotated</th>
         <th class="rotate" rowspan="2">Topic 2 Rotated</th>
         <th class="rotate" rowspan="2">Topic 3 Rotated</th>
         <th class="rotate" rowspan="2">Topic 4 Rotated</th>
         <th class="rotate" rowspan="2">Topic 5 Rotated</th>
         <th class="rotate" rowspan="2">Topic 6 Rotated</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>
            1</th>
         <th>
            2</th>
         <th>
            3</th>
         <th>
            4</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>01</td>
         <td>02</td>
         <td>03</td>
         <td>04</td>
         <td>05</td>
         <td>06</td>
         <td>07</td>
         <td>08</td>
         <td>09</td>
         <td>10</td>
         <td>11</td>
         <td>12</td>
         <td>13</td>
         <td>14</td>
         <td>15</td>
         <td>Lorem ispum Lorem ispum Lorem ispum Lorem ispum Lorem ispum Lorem ispum Lorem ispum Lorem ispum Lorem ispum</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>01</td>
         <td>02</td>
         <td>03</td>
         <td>04</td>
         <td>05</td>
         <td>06</td>
         <td>07</td>
         <td>08</td>
         <td>09</td>
         <td>10</td>
         <td>11</td>
         <td>12</td>
         <td>13</td>
         <td>14</td>
         <td>15</td>
         <td>Lorem ispum Lorem ispum Lorem ispum Lorem ispum Lorem ispum Lorem ispum Lorem ispum Lorem ispum Lorem ispum</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>01</td>
         <td>02</td>
         <td>03</td>
         <td>04</td>
         <td>05</td>
         <td>06</td>
         <td>07</td>
         <td>08</td>
         <td>09</td>
         <td>10</td>
         <td>11</td>
         <td>12</td>
         <td>13</td>
         <td>14</td>
         <td>15</td>
         <td>Lorem ispum Lorem ispum Lorem ispum Lorem ispum Lorem ispum Lorem ispum Lorem ispum Lorem ispum Lorem ispum</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```